# HttpClient базовая автризация

Tags: java, auth, httpclient

После вроде как успешной базовой авторизации последующие запросы все равно возвращают 401 хранилище для кук настроил но не помогло

```
@org.junit.Test
public void doGet() {
    String url = "http://localhost:85/orders";
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin"+":"+"admin").getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin"+":"+"admin").getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    System.out.println("executing req = " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = client.execute(httpPost).getEntity();
        System.out.println(entity.getContent());
        entity = client.execute(httpGet).getEntity();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у запрашиваемого ресурса не создаётся сессионная кука. Или аутентификация требуется для каждого запроса. Попробуйте добавлять заголовок к каждому запросу.

Еще можно настроить провайдера для basic аутнтификации:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
 = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
  .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
  .build();
```

Comment: да так и решил проблему, сервер  jetty настроил с помощью LoginService и базовой авторизации.
Неужели базовая авторизация не подразумевает сессии?

Comment: Видимо зависит от сервера приложений и/или от настроек аутентификации. Недавно тестировал сервис, там достаточно было при первом запросе авторизоваться. В последующих запросах достаточно было передавать куку jsession.